# Openlayers Handle Custom Server Tiles

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

If i'm going to have my own server that generate the image tiles based on the zoom resolution (which is not a MapServer or OsGeo).
I was checking the WMS and TMS layers specifications, my question is there a protocol i can use in the server side that let me respond to "Openlyers" without client manual tiles handling? and what is the Openlayers layer used for custom connection?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. TMS and WMTS have preset zoom levels, and pixel sizes, while WMS allows you to request an image with any geographic and pixel width/height you want. So, if you want arbitrary resolutions, WMS is what you need.

Comment: So if i use WMS and i have a custom server and want to respond to openlayers requests, what is the standards for requests and responses.

Comment: Look at this example, http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/lite.html, open a developer console and look at the query string. You will see what parameters you need to provide.

Comment: As i understood ... the image division into tiles is done from the openlayers side and in the server i just need to respond to instance tile request with specific parameters like bbox and format.
   
http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?LAYERS=basic&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=90,0,135,45&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

Comment: Yes. You are creating the wms server yourself, no?

Comment: Yes, my server side is a servlet that has access to my map and can divide it base on the BBOX parameter that sent from Openlayers ... i'm implementing this solution now ... thanks for your kind help.